# How to get JSON in eclipse from this web php? from AndroidHive tutorial

Tags: php, json, eclipse

How to get JSON?  i don't know how to get tag from this php. I like here the function 'autenticate'

private static String login_tag = "login"? if userLoggedIn can to add task.

```
<?php
require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
require_once '../include/PassHash.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// User id from db - Global Variable
$user_id = NULL;

/**
 * Adding Middle Layer to authenticate every request
 * Checking if the request has valid api key in the 'Authorization' header
 */
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
// Getting request headers
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$response = array();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

// Verifying Authorization Header
if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    $db = new DbHandler();

    // get the api key
    $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
    // validating api key
    if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
        // api key is not present in users table
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
        echoRespnse(401, $response);
        $app->stop();
    } else {
        global $user_id;
        // get user primary key id
        $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
    }
} else {
    // api key is missing in header
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
    echoRespnse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
    }
}

/**
 * ----------- METHODS WITHOUT AUTHENTICATION ---------------------------------
 */
/**
 * User Registration
 * url - /register
 * method - POST
 * params - name, email, password
 */
$app->post('/register', function() use ($app) {
        // check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'email', 'password'));

        $response = array();

        // reading post params
        $name = $app->request->post('name');
        $email = $app->request->post('email');
        $password = $app->request->post('password');

        // validating email address
        validateEmail($email);

        $db = new DbHandler();
        $res = $db->createUser($name, $email, $password);

        if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
        } else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
        } else if ($res == USER_ALREADY_EXISTED) {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Sorry, this email already existed";
        }
        // echo json response
        echoRespnse(201, $response);
    });

/**
 * User Login
 * url - /login
 * method - POST
 * params - email, password
 */
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
        // check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('email', 'password'));

        // reading post params
        $email = $app->request()->post('email');
        $password = $app->request()->post('password');
        $response = array();

        $db = new DbHandler();
        // check for correct email and password
        if ($db->checkLogin($email, $password)) {
            // get the user by email
            $user = $db->getUserByEmail($email);

            if ($user != NULL) {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response['name'] = $user['name'];
                $response['email'] = $user['email'];
                $response['apiKey'] = $user['api_key'];
                $response['createdAt'] = $user['created_at'];
            } else {
                // unknown error occurred
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "An error occurred. Please try again";
            }
        } else {
            // user credentials are wrong
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Login failed. Incorrect credentials';
        }

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });

/*
 * ------------------------ METHODS WITH AUTHENTICATION ------------------------
 */
/**
 * Listing all tasks of particual user
 * method GET
 * url /tasks          
 */
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // fetching all user tasks
        $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["tasks"] = array();

        // looping through result and preparing tasks array
        while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["id"] = $task["id"];
            $tmp["task"] = $task["task"];
            $tmp["status"] = $task["status"];
            $tmp["createdAt"] = $task["created_at"];
            array_push($response["tasks"], $tmp);
        }

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });

/**
 * Listing single task of particual user
 * method GET
 * url /tasks/:id
 * Will return 404 if the task doesn't belongs to user
 */
$app->get('/tasks/:id', 'authenticate', function($task_id) {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // fetch task
        $result = $db->getTask($task_id, $user_id);

        if ($result != NULL) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["id"] = $result["id"];
            $response["task"] = $result["task"];
            $response["status"] = $result["status"];
            $response["createdAt"] = $result["created_at"];
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
            echoRespnse(404, $response);
        }
    });

/**
 * Creating new task in db
 * method POST
 * params - name
 * url - /tasks/
 */
$app->post('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) {
        // check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('task'));

        $response = array();
        $task = $app->request->post('task');

        global $user_id;
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // creating new task
        $task_id = $db->createTask($user_id, $task);

        if ($task_id != NULL) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Task created successfully";
            $response["task_id"] = $task_id;
            echoRespnse(201, $response);
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to create task. Please try again";
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        }            
    });

/**
 * Updating existing task
 * method PUT
 * params task, status
 * url - /tasks/:id
 */
$app->put('/tasks/:id', 'authenticate', function($task_id) use($app) {
        // check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('task', 'status'));

        global $user_id;            
        $task = $app->request->put('task');
        $status = $app->request->put('status');

        $db = new DbHandler();
        $response = array();

        // updating task
        $result = $db->updateTask($user_id, $task_id, $task, $status);
        if ($result) {
            // task updated successfully
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Task updated successfully";
        } else {
            // task failed to update
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Task failed to update. Please try again!";
        }
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });

/**
 * Deleting task. Users can delete only their tasks

 * method DELETE
 * url /tasks
 */
$app->delete('/tasks/:id', 'authenticate', function($task_id) use($app) {
        global $user_id;

        $db = new DbHandler();
        $response = array();
        $result = $db->deleteTask($user_id, $task_id);
        if ($result) {
            // task deleted successfully
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Task deleted succesfully";
        } else {
            // task failed to delete
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Task failed to delete. Please try again!";
        }
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });

/**
 * Verifying required params posted or not
 */

function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
$error = false;
$error_fields = "";
$request_params = array();
$request_params = $_REQUEST;
// Handling PUT request params
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
}
foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
    if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
        $error = true;
        $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
    }
}

if ($error) {
    // Required field(s) are missing or empty
    // echo error json and stop the app
    $response = array();
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
    echoRespnse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
}
}
/**
 * Validating email address
 */
function validateEmail($email) {
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = 'Email address is not valid';
    echoRespnse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
}
}

/**
 * Echoing json response to client
 * @param String $status_code Http response code
 * @param Int $response Json response
 */

function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
// Http response code
$app->status($status_code);

// setting response content type to json
$app->contentType('application/json');

echo json_encode($response);
}

$app->run();
?>
```

DBHandler.php is here

```
<?php

/**
 * Class to handle all db operations
 * This class will have CRUD methods for database tables
 *
 * @author Ravi Tamada
 * @link URL Tutorial link
 */
class DbHandler {

private $conn;

function __construct() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
    // opening db connection
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

/* ------------- `users` table method ------------------ */

/**
 * Creating new user
 * @param String $name User full name
 * @param String $email User login email id
 * @param String $password User login password
 */
public function createUser($name, $email, $password) {
    require_once 'PassHash.php';
    $response = array();

    // First check if user already existed in db
    if (!$this->isUserExists($email)) {
        // Generating password hash
        $password_hash = PassHash::hash($password);

        // Generating API key
        $api_key = $this->generateApiKey();

        // insert query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password_hash, api_key, status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, 1)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $password_hash, $api_key);

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        // Check for successful insertion
        if ($result) {
            // User successfully inserted
            return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        } else {
            // Failed to create user
            return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
        }
    } else {
        // User with same email already existed in the db
        return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
    }

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Checking user login
 * @param String $email User login email id
 * @param String $password User login password
 * @return boolean User login status success/fail
 */
public function checkLogin($email, $password) {
    // fetching user by email
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($password_hash);

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // Found user with the email
        // Now verify the password

        $stmt->fetch();

        $stmt->close();

        if (PassHash::check_password($password_hash, $password)) {
            // User password is correct
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            // user password is incorrect
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        $stmt->close();

        // user not existed with the email
        return FALSE;
    }
}

/**
 * Checking for duplicate user by email address
 * @param String $email email to check in db
 * @return boolean
 */
private function isUserExists($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_rows > 0;
}

/**
 * Fetching user by email
 * @param String $email User email id
 */
public function getUserByEmail($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, api_key, status, created_at FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $email, $api_key, $status, $created_at);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $user = array();
        $user["name"] = $name;
        $user["email"] = $email;
        $user["api_key"] = $api_key;
        $user["status"] = $status;
        $user["created_at"] = $created_at;
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching user api key
 * @param String $user_id user id primary key in user table
 */
public function getApiKeyById($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT api_key FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // $api_key = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        // TODO
        $stmt->bind_result($api_key);
        $stmt->close();
        return $api_key;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching user id by api key
 * @param String $api_key user api key
 */
public function getUserId($api_key) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE api_key = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $api_key);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // TODO
        // $user_id = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $user_id;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Validating user api key
 * If the api key is there in db, it is a valid key
 * @param String $api_key user api key
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isValidApiKey($api_key) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from users WHERE api_key = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $api_key);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_rows > 0;
}

/**
 * Generating random Unique MD5 String for user Api key
 */
private function generateApiKey() {
    return md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}

/* ------------- `tasks` table method ------------------ */

/**
 * Creating new task
 * @param String $user_id user id to whom task belongs to
 * @param String $task task text
 */
public function createTask($user_id, $task) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks(task) VALUES(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $task);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if ($result) {
        // task row created
        // now assign the task to user
        $new_task_id = $this->conn->insert_id;
        $res = $this->createUserTask($user_id, $new_task_id);
        if ($res) {
            // task created successfully
            return $new_task_id;
        } else {
            // task failed to create
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        // task failed to create
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching single task
 * @param String $task_id id of the task
 */
public function getTask($task_id, $user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.id, t.task, t.status, t.created_at from tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ? AND ut.task_id = t.id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $task_id, $user_id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $res = array();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);
        // TODO
        // $task = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $res["id"] = $id;
        $res["task"] = $task;
        $res["status"] = $status;
        $res["created_at"] = $created_at;
        $stmt->close();
        return $res;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching all user tasks
 * @param String $user_id id of the user
 */
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}

/**
 * Updating task
 * @param String $task_id id of the task
 * @param String $task task text
 * @param String $status task status
 */
public function updateTask($user_id, $task_id, $task, $status) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE tasks t, user_tasks ut set t.task = ?, t.status = ? WHERE t.id = ? AND t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("siii", $task, $status, $task_id, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_affected_rows > 0;
}

/**
 * Deleting a task
 * @param String $task_id id of the task to delete
 */
public function deleteTask($user_id, $task_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE t FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ? AND ut.task_id = t.id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $task_id, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    return $num_affected_rows > 0;
}

/* ------------- `user_tasks` table method ------------------ */

/**
 * Function to assign a task to user
 * @param String $user_id id of the user
 * @param String $task_id id of the task
 */
public function createUserTask($user_id, $task_id) {


 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_tasks(user_id, task_id) values(?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $task_id);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if (false === $result) {
        die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}

}

?>
```

[full source](http://download.androidhive.info/download.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like there [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)! and there [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)!